# How can I run MongoDB commands by querying the special $cmd collection?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to implement a MongoDB driver (actually I'm not implementing it from scratch, I'm improving an existing small one, but that's irrelevant). Issuing commands to MongoDB appears to simply be performed via special queries to the `$cmd` collection. This is described in the [MongoDB glossary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cmd) as follows:

> #### $cmd
>
> A special virtual collection that exposes MongoDB’s database commands. To use database commands, see Issue Commands.

Okay. So how do I do that? How about looking at [Use Database Commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/)?

> Many drivers provide an equivalent for the `db.runCommand()` method. Internally, running commands with `db.runCommand()` is equivalent to a special query against the `$cmd` collection.

Um, okay. That's not helpful. I'm *writing* a driver, not using one.

Is there documentation somewhere for how to actually implement `runCommand` functionality? How are the queries against `$cmd` supposed to work?

Comment: Probably looking at how other drivers have implemented it would help. You can see the command method of pymongo which is similar to runCommand. Here is the link - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/a7575fa14f5a9aaeb0149981899f776af9e1ad1c/pymongo/database.py

Comment: KInd of interesting to consider which language you are considering writing a driver for, as I think there is pretty broad coverage on that already, though some language implementations could undoubtedly be better. You can always drop me a line on chat (since you have the required reputation to do so ) if you really need to create a new language driver or simply "build a better mouse trap".

Answer (score 1):

> How are the queries against $cmd supposed to work?

A database command is a query on a special collection, `$cmd`,
where the query selector defines the command itself. So, query equivalent for running a command using `db.runCommand({isMaster: 1})` is:

```
db.$cmd.findOne({isMaster: 1})
```

In my machine, they both generated the following result:

```
{
        "ismaster" : true,
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
        "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
        "localTime" : ISODate("2016-04-22T12:46:02.378Z"),
        "maxWireVersion" : 4,
        "minWireVersion" : 0,
        "ok" : 1
}
```