# What's the $cmd collection in MongoDB? How can i use it?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB's documentation defines `$cmd` as following:

> A special virtual collection that exposes MongoDB’s database commands.
>   To use database commands, see Issue Commands.

And in the [Issue Commands](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/#issue-commands) section:

> running commands with `db.runCommand()` is equivalent to a special query
>   against the `$cmd` collection

But when I'm issuing this query against `$cmd` collection:

```
db.$cmd.find({isMaster: 1})
```

I got the following error:

> { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "bad numberToReturn (0) for $cmd type ns - can
>   only be 1 or -1", "code" : 16979 }

Anyway, What's the `$cmd` collection? and How can I properly issue a query against it?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642311/

Comment: @chridam There is no answer for that, either!

Comment: Which does not make your _question_ less duplicate.

Comment: Well, this is a virtual collection and may not have implemented public interfaces to interact with it the way we do with normal collections. It's meant to be used internally. see code for `db.runCommand`. You'll see it's internally calling `_runCommandImpl` and there is no code for it. Bottom line is that you'll have to call internal commands using `db.runCommand`

Comment: @Saleem Sounds like you should make this an answer to the original question, maybe a bit beefed up. ;)

Comment: hmm. well I'll see if I can get enough legit supporting material to make it as an answer.

Comment: @Saleem Apparently `_runCommandImpl` delegates to `this.getMongo().runCommand(name, obj, options)` and when i run `db.getMongo().runCommand`, i get `function runCommand() {
    [native code]
}`

Comment: yes, you got point. native code. undocumented interfaces.

Comment: @Saleem Using `findOne` i could run the command..I wrote an answer and it's community wiki..If you will, you can edit it and answer the first part of the question

Comment: Sure please. Community wiki is good place to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit digging and experimenting with `mongo`, i found that using `findOne` method i can actually run a query against the `$cmd` collection successfully. So:

> How can I properly issue a query against it?

Issue a query with `findOne`:

```
db.$cmd.findOne({isMaster: 1})
```

Would have the same result as `db.runCommand({isMaster: 1})`, which is like following:

```
{
        "ismaster" : true,
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
        "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
        "localTime" : ISODate("2016-04-22T12:26:21.350Z"),
        "maxWireVersion" : 4,
        "minWireVersion" : 0,
        "ok" : 1
}
```